# How to add a new date and value for only one of the columns of an existing dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, append, concatenation

I have a data-frame with date as the index and columns for a few companies' stock prices. I want to append a few new dates at the bottom but with only one of the cos' stock price filled in. How can I do that? I have tried append and concat but am running into issues because I am updating only one co's stock price.

Lets say this is the dataframe:

```
       Co1    Co2   Co3   Co4
Date 1  100   200   300   400
Date 2  105   210   290   350
Date 3  102   205   325   380
```

I want to add Co3's prices for two new dates from a data-series, lets say:

```
Date
Date 4  300
Date 5  310
Date 6  305
Name:Co3, Length:3, dtype:float64
```

Would appreciate if anyone can guide!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's try [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas-concat)

```
print(Co3)

Date
Date 4    300
Date 5    310
Date 6    305
Name: Co3, dtype: int64

pd.concat([df1, pd.DataFrame(Co3)]).fillna(0.0)
```

---

```
          Co1    Co2  Co3    Co4
Date                            
Date 1  100.0  200.0  300  400.0
Date 2  105.0  210.0  290  350.0
Date 3  102.0  205.0  325  380.0
Date 4    0.0    0.0  300    0.0
Date 5    0.0    0.0  310    0.0
Date 6    0.0    0.0  305    0.0
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but its not appending to the original dataframe. Also ideally I don't want to fill NaNs with 0s

Comment: Remove `fillna` and assign result of `pd.concat` to original frame

Comment: Thanks, will try. My understanding was that assign is used only to add a nee column or replace all values of an entire existing column. Will this do the latter, and also add new dates and values to relevant column of the dataframe (Co3)